# usage of a dash

Tags: punctuation, multiple-negation

Consider these two sentences:

> 1. Without any atmosphere, there cannot be any weather – no wind, no rain, no clouds.
> 2. Without any atmosphere, there cannot be any weather – wind, rain, clouds.

My question is: Can I use "negative verb" and "no" in a sentence where a dash is used?

Comment: Not only is 1 better, as @stangdon said, but 2 isn't really a correct sentence unless you add an "or": "wind, rain, **or** clouds"

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use a dash with negative sentences or the word "no".  In fact, I think #1, with "no", reads better than #2.  Did you see something that suggested that you couldn't use a dash?  I'm wondering if there's some rule that we might be able to clarify for you.

I see that you tagged your question "double negation", but this is not really a double negative.  A double negative is something like "I did not eat **no** bread" or, to use your example, "Without any atmosphere, there cannot be **no** weather."

I think the thing that might be confusing you is this: ["A dash is sometimes used to set off concluding lists and explanations in a more informal and abrupt manner than the colon."](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/GRAMMAR/marks/dash.htm)  That's what's happening here: we say there would be no weather, and then list the things that would not exist; that list forms a separate clause, which is why it's not double negation.  It's like a shortened version of "Without any atmosphere, there cannot be any weather.  For example, there would be no wind, no rain, and no clouds."